# Disable firing TextChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, textchanged, lostfocus

I have **textbox** and I'm changing the text inside it when `lostFocus` is fired but that also fires up the `textChanged` event, which I'm handling but I don't want it to be fired in this one case, how can I disable it here?

### UPDATE:

The idea with `bool` is good but I have couple of textboxes and I use the same event for all of them, so it's not working exactly as I want the way I want.

Now it's working! :

```
private bool setFire = true;

private void mytextbox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (this.IsLoaded)
      { 
          System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textbox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
                    
          if(textbox.Text.ToString().Contains('.'))
          {
             textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
             textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

             setFire = false;
             textbox.Text = "something else";
             setFire = true;
          }
                    
      }
   }
    
private void mytextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if ((this.IsLoaded) && setFire)
      {
         System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textbox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
                    
         if(textbox.Text.ToString().Contains('.'))
         {
            textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
         }  
       }
       
       setFire = true;
   }
```

I managed to put the `bool` back on `true` after editing the text and it works so thx guys :]

Comment: then modify @Tigran idea `private Dictionary<TextBox, bool> setFire = ...`

Comment: No need to have a Dictionary IMHO. A list of String is sufficient as shown in my example.

Comment: Do not post the solution as part of the question! If someone answered it, simple "accept" is enough. If you didn't get a satisfactory answer, but came up with your own solution, post it as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simpliest way that I can think of is using conditnional `bool` variable. 
When you are going to set the text on `LostFocus` set it to `true` and inside `textChanged` event handler check if that `bool` variable is `true`, do not do nothing.

Answer (score 13):

Just remove the event handler and then add it after you've done what you need to.

```
private void mytextbox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.mytextbox.TextChanged -= this.myTextBox_TextChanged;

  if(textbox.Text.ToString().Contains('.'))
  {
         textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
         textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
  }

  this.mytextbox.TextChanged += this.myTextBox_TextChanged;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you could also simply use the "IsFocused" bool built into the UI.

```
private void mytextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (!textbox.IsLoaded || !textbox.IsFocused)
        return;
     
                
    if(textbox.Text.ToString().Contains('.'))
    {
        textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }  
}
```

This way you don't need a unique bool for each input.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I feel.. We can do this in Best way and easy way..!

```
//My textbox value will be set from other methods
txtNetPayAmount.Text = "Ravindra.pc"; //I wanted to avoide this to travel in my complex logic in TextChanged

private void txtNetPayAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _strLoanPayment = Convert.ToString(txtNetPayAmount.Text).Trim();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strLoanPayment)) return;
            if(!_isPayAmountEntered) return;

            //Some logic.. Avoided to run each time on this text change
        }

        private bool _isPayAmountEntered = false;
        private void txtNetPayAmount_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _isPayAmountEntered = true;
        }

        private void txtNetPayAmount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _isPayAmountEntered = false;
        }

        private void txtNetPayAmount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            _isPayAmountEntered = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Textboxes, just use a List of String where you store the textboxes whose state is `DoNotFire`.

**Your updated code (Also improved other things):**

```
private List<string> doNotFireTextBoxes = new List<string>();

private void mytextbox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (this.IsLoaded)
      {      
          System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textbox = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) sender;
          doNotFireTextBoxes.Add(textbox.Name)  

          if(textbox.Text.Contains('.'))
          {
             textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
             textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
          }

      }
   }

private void mytextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (this.IsLoaded)
      {
         System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textbox = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) sender;
         if(!doNotFireTextBoxes.Contains(textbox.Name))
         {
             if(textbox.Text.Contains('.'))
             {
                textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
             }
         }
         doNotFireTextBoxes.Remove(txtBoxName)
       }
   }
```